# python keystroke classifier 

Tags: python, io

I need to write a program that does the following:

1. User enters a character
2. The program outputs whether it is alphabetic, numeric, a space, or a newline.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for [python string methods](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/string-methods.html) should give you exactly what you are looking for.